# Swift 2.1 not recognizing my class

Tags: ios, class, import, swift2, xcode7.1

I have `clipsTableViewController.swift` file which contain `clipsTableViewController` class in this class I called `DataManager` class from another swift file which I created in project using cmnd+N and selecting swift file. But I get this confusing error message : `Use of Unresolved Identifier DataManager`

you can see it in the picture below : 
[image]

DataManager class : 
[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: check your DataManager.swift file target ownership and make sure it is same with your tableview file

Comment: can you show class declaration?

Comment: @rkyr i've put my class picture in the post

Comment: @zp_x Thanks i marked my project test owner and it recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check files Target Membership on the right side of xcode and make sure test files is selected.